# JavaScript - Retrieve variable value generated inside the for loop, externally

Tags: javascript, json

Well, I am working with a rest API that fetch information from the same database, but two different tables:

Table #1 contains(Outputs JSON results that contains the below objects):

id 
name 
type

Table #2 contains(Outputs JSON results that contains the below objects):

id
value (real-time, updated periodically)

What I want to do is to compare the **id** in Table #1 and compare it to **id** 
in Table #2 and if there is a match between the two id's outputs the sum of (value) from Table #2 with all the values having the same id.

Until now what I am able to do is the following:

**File1.js**

```
    require('File2.js');

    for (a in metricsData){
    var metricsID =  metricsData[a].id;
    }

    /* Certainly the below code is not working, but I don't know if it should
    be done this way or it can be much more better.

    Can't get the values of both metricsID & idFromLoad

    if(metricsID === idFromLoad)  {
     var sum += value;
     console.log('The new sum is : '+sum)
    } */
```

**File2.js**

```
for(var i in load.updates){
    var idFromLoad =     load.updates[i].id;
    var newVal = load.updates[i].value;
}
```

So, the big question is how to get the values of both **metricsID** & **idFromLoad** outside of the for loop? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is a little confusing, but to answer the question as described in the title of this post...

Because you have the variable defined inside the loop, it only exists inside the loop. If you want to "remember" the value outside of the loop, you would need to define it outside:

```
var metricsID;
for (a in metricsData){
    metricsID =  metricsData[a].id;
}
```

Note though, that outside the loop, it's value will equal the id of the last item in the loop.

If you are looking for an easy way to look up values in both tables, what you could do is loop through each once and create a map keyed off the id so that you can easily retrieve the value based on the id.

```
var updatesMap = {};

for(var i in load.updates){
    var idFromLoad =     load.updates[i].id;
    updatesMap[idFromLoad] = load.updates[i].value;
}
```

Then in your other loop:

```
for (a in metricsData){
    var metricsID =  metricsData[a].id;
    var updateValue = updatesMap[meticsID]; //this is the value from the other table
}
```